# sending images using Django Channels

Tags: django, django-channels

I have a common chat message model in my Django project. The Message model looks like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    writer = ...

    chatroom = ...
    body = models.TextField(verbose_name="Body", null=True, blank=True)
    imagemsg = models.ImageField(upload_to='message/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
```

Then in my consumer i send the **body** to front end like this:

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncConsumer):


async def websocket_receive(self, event):
        ...
        myresponse = {
            "message": msg,
            'username': username,
        }

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                "type": "chat_message",
                "text": json.dumps(myresponse),
            }
        )
```

also this is how front end sends data to backend:

```
socket.onopen = function (e) {

    formData.submit(function (event) {
        var finalData = {
            "text": msg.val()
        };
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(finalData));
    });
}
```

so, with this texts can be sent back and forth with no issue, and the real-time behaviours happening ok. Now I want to have the same behaviour for the images. i.e.,  send them from `socket.onopen` and then send them back using `async def websocket_receive`.

Unfortunately, I can't find much documentation anywhere. So I was wondering if someone can give me a hint as to how to achieve this. Or even if this is the right approach.

Comment: Have you got a solution for this?

Comment: @Danny i store the image and send the url via websocket